# Change size vba array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vba, excel

I have a VBA macro in Excel which calls a DLL written in C++. The function in this DLL returns an array to the macro, which is then put into the Excel sheet.

VBA macro:

```
Private Declare Function arrayTestEXL Lib "C:\Path\To\Lib\calcDLL.dll" (ByRef testArray As Double) As Long
Sub testArrayTest()
Dim testArray(0, 9) As Double
Dim rngResults As Range
Dim errorCode As Integer

errorCode = arrayTestEXL(testArray(0, 0))
Set rngResults = Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(4, 13))
rngResults.Value = testArray

End Sub
```

And the C++ code is:

```
int _stdcall arrayTest(double* testArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        testArray[i] = i;
    return 0;
}
```

This works. Now I want to change the size of the array from within the C++ function.

If I add:

```
testArray = (double*) malloc(10 * sizeof(double))
```

To the function (before the loop obviously), then suddenly all the values become 0 as they are put into Excel.

Comment: That is because you are losing the memory pointed to by testArray, by assigning testArray a newly allocated memory address. Since the buffer is given to your function by the caller, you should increase the array size at the caller site and provide the size of that buffer as a second parameter to the arrayTest method.

Comment: @SelçukCihan This makes sense. Thank you.